# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline - how to display Gatling results?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gatling

What I would like to do is for Jenkins to display the HTML report produced by a Gatling simulation somewhere there around the Job page.

I'm using the Declarative Pipeline syntax and running Gatling in a docker container.

Here is the code:

```
sh '''docker run -i -d --net=host --name gatlingAG ubuntu
      docker cp gatling gatlingAG:/
      docker exec gatlingAG apt-get -qq update
      docker exec gatlingAG apt-get -qq install default-jdk
      docker exec gatlingAG /bin/bash -c "./gatling/bin/gatling.sh -m"'''
```

After the simulation is finished, the results are created in *TestResults/[name_of_simulation]* folder within the docker container.

I can't seem to find a way on the internet to reach that folder, and the *index.html* file inside, to display the results in Jenkins. How to do that?

Comment: Kindof unclear if this is a Jenkins question vs. Docker question.  Which one do you really need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly just a quick word on using Docker:

Where Docker shines is when you use it to build immutable infrastructure i.e. Containers that don't change. To that end, Docker supports the [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) which allows you to build up containers via a number of different steps such as installing Gatling and also setting the default command to be run in the container when it starts.

By using the Dockerfile approach, you could build a Gatling container that you use for your tests, and that would free you up from having to run the `docker exec gatlingAG apt-get -qq update` type statements each time your pipeline runs in Jenkins. Just something to consider.

Now onto your problem of archiving the output of Gatling via your Jenkins pipeline. There are two ways that you can approach this:

1. Use `docker cp` to copy the results back out of the container into the Jenkins workspace for your pipeline
2. Mount the workspace into the Gatling container, so that results are written directly to the workspace and can be easily archived

**1: Using docker cp**

You already use `docker cp` to copy things into the container, so you can just use that to copy things back out again after Gatling has run. You could do something like this:

```
sh '''docker run -i -d --net=host --name gatlingAG ubuntu
              docker cp gatling gatlingAG:/
              docker exec gatlingAG apt-get -qq update
              docker exec gatlingAG apt-get -qq install default-jdk
              docker exec gatlingAG /bin/bash -c "./gatling/bin/gatling.sh -m"'''
              docker cp gatlingAG:/gatling/[name_of_run] .
```

That would copy the output from the container filesystem to your workspace filesystem, from where you can archive it (see bottom of the answer).

**2: Mounting the Jenkins workspace into the container**

Docker supports mounting filesystems from the host machine into any containers that run on it. By doing that, processes within the container can write files onto more reliable storage or storage that outlasts the life of the container (as soon as you destroy a container its filesystem is lost forever)

Again you could do something like this with your pipeline definition:

```
sh '''docker run -i -d --net=host -v $(pwd)/gatling:/gatling --name gatlingAG ubuntu
              docker exec gatlingAG apt-get -qq update
              docker exec gatlingAG apt-get -qq install default-jdk
              docker exec gatlingAG /bin/bash -c "./gatling/bin/gatling.sh -m"'''
```

You'll notice that I'm using the `-v` option when running the container to tell Docker to mount the gatling directory at /gatling in your container. That means you don't need to copy it in. Also when Gatling runs, the results will be written directly to your workspace, meaning that you can easily archive them one Gatling has finished. You may need to make sure that the results of any previous Gatling run are cleaned from the workspace before you run the pipeline again.

**Archiving the results**

Finally, once you have the output of the Gatling run in your workspace, you can simply archive it using the [archive](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts) Jenkins pipeline directive. This will mean that Jenkins stores the HTML as an artifact of the job. You can then access the HTML directly via your browser e.g.

`https://jenkins-url/job/gatlin-job/1/artifact/TestResults/[name_of_simulation]/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to accomplish.

At the end of your Jenkins build, add a post-build step like this:

```
cd serviceModule
mvn clean test-compile gatling:test -Dtest.env=${ENV} -DDB.password=${PASSWORD} -Dtest.type=${TYPE} -Dusers=${users} -Dduration=${duration} -Dtest.hostname=${HOST} -Dtest.port=${PORT}

export REPORT_NAME=$(head -n 1 target/gatling/lastRun.txt)
echo $REPORT_NAME
ls target/gatling/$REPORT_NAME
cp -rf target/gatling/$REPORT_NAME target/gatling/HTMLReport
```

Probably a few ways you could do this.   This will work with Docker **if you MAP the results folder (from within Docker container) to the Jenkins workspace correctly**.

Then, after that step archive the report using the Jenkins "Public HTML Reports" plugin, from the `target/gatling/HTMLReport` folder.

This is how I do it with Karate test wrapped in Gatling.